# How to get back true color mode in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, display

I have a Windows 7 x86 VM which I run in Virtual Box. 
Sometimes, when I play Alpha Centaurie, it ends with the VM only displaying 256 colors. 
When I go to Screen Resoltution, I only see:
[image]

I tried rebooting the VM, but that never helps.
Playing Aplha Centaurie again sometimes helps.

Is there a way to enable True Color Mode again?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution. I have to go to Advanced settings and click on List all Modes
[image]. Then a listbox open where I can selecta True color mode
[image]

Comment: What a life-saver--this was driving me nuts.